# Redhawk 1.10 and gnuhawk components

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm using Redhawk v1.10 and uploaded the integration redhawk components to the target sdr.
 I get  the following error when I attempt to launch any of the uploaded gnuhawk components to the target sdr:

`Failed to launch "component name" Unable to load software package 'deps/gnuhawk/gnuhawk.spdml'(dependency of software package 'component name', implementation 'cpp')`

Comment: How did you install the components?

Comment: I copied them to my sdr/dom/component directory and refreshed the components under the target sdr directory in Redhawk ide. I also tried to importing the gnuhawk components by doing File->Import->Existing Projects into Workspace->Browse to the directory with the integration-gnuhawk-develop-1.9 directory.

Comment: Do you know how the components were compiled?  Is this originating from a source install or an RPM install?  If a source install, what steps did you go through to compile the packages?  If an RPM install, what version of RPMs are you working with?

Comment: I'm using the Centos 6 64 bit RPM on the http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/download.html. Also I'm trying to use these gnuhawk components:https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/integration-gnuhawk on Redhawk v1.10.

Answer (score 0):

Although the components haven't been updated for 1.10, they should still be compatible.
Here are two options you could try:
1) Make sure your GPP is running if you are launching the component to an active domain.
2) Open up a terminal window, go into the component directory and run `$ ./build.sh` this should generate a new file that you can move into the cpp folder. It should be called .cpp. For some reason, RH isn't picking up the old cpp files but will pick up these new files. It's worth a shot.

Let me know if either of those work.

Comment: I tried both of your suggest answers. My GPP is running successfully, but on the other hand when I running the ./build.sh in the components directory I get the following error below:   No package 'gsl' found    Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable  gsl_CFLAGS and gsl_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config  See the pkg-config man page for more details

Comment: I also tried running the ./build.sh inside each individual component and get the following error message below:  ./configure line 4491: syntax error near unexpected token '${GHAWK_DIR}'                                                        ./configure line 4491: 'GNUHAWK_PKG_CONFIG (${GHAWK_DIR})'

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to installing the GNUHAWK components from source: compiling/installing the GNUHAWK soft package dependency and compiling/installing the individual components.  Your error implies that the first step was not completed.

First, you will need a few dependencies:

```
# yum install orc-devel gsl-devel python-cheetah cmake
```

Second, compile and install the GNUHAWK soft package dependency.  This will take a while to complete.

1. Navigate to the top-level GNUHAWK source code directory.
2. Run these commands:

   ```
   $ ./reconf; ./configure; make -j8 ; sudo make install
   ```

Third, compile and install the GNUHAWK components.  This will also take a while to complete.

1. Navigate to the components directory

   ```
   $ cd components
   ```
2. Run these commands

   ```
   $ ./reconf; ./configure; make -j8 ; sudo make install
   ```

To make things run a little faster, you can try running more than 8 compile jobs (e.g., "make -j16"); however, setting the number of jobs too high (i.e., unlimited: "make -j") can lock up your machine due to the large number of components that will be built in parallel.